How to select child Entity all record name/title into parent Entity list as single property with comma separated string
contents:  [{
  title: 'Test Content IV',
  type: 'link',
  category: 'Category',
  keywords: 'tset,test',
  updated_at: 2024-05-13T12:21:28.018Z,
  is_disabled: true
},
{
  title: 'Test Content IV',
  type: 'link',
  category: 'This is testing',
  keywords: 'tset,test',
  updated_at: 2024-05-13T12:21:28.018Z,
  is_disabled: true
},
{
  title: 'Test Content IV',
  type: 'link',
  category: 'Fall Prevention',
  keywords: 'tset,test',
  updated_at: 2024-05-13T12:21:28.018Z,
  is_disabled: true
}]

The above result is from the following query. It is duplicating the content due to multiple categories against that content
const queryBuilder = this.contentRepository
      .createQueryBuilder(`${contentEntity}`)
      .select([
        `${contentEntity}.title AS title`,
        `${contentEntity}.type AS type`,
        `category.name AS category`,
        `${contentEntity}.keywords as keywords`,
        `${contentEntity}.updated_at as updated_at`,
        `${contentEntity}.is_disabled AS is_disabled`,
      ])
      .leftJoin(
        `${contentEntity}.contentCategories`,
        'contentCategories',
      )
      .leftJoin('contentCategories.category', 'category');

const content = await queryBuilder.getRawMany();

I Have tried the with STRING_AGG but that creates the issue GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
 const queryBuilder = this.contentRepository
      .createQueryBuilder(`${contentEntity}`)
      .select([
        `${contentEntity}.title AS title`,
        `${contentEntity}.type AS type`,
        `STRING_AGG(category.name, ', ') AS category`,
        `${contentEntity}.keywords as keywords`,
        `${contentEntity}.updated_at as updated_at`,
        `${contentEntity}.is_disabled AS is_disabled`,
      ])
      .leftJoin(
        `${contentEntity}.contentCategories`,
        'contentCategories',
      )
      .leftJoin('contentCategories.category', 'category')
      .groupBy(`${contentEntity}.title`);

const content = await queryBuilder.getRawMany();

What I want the response writing below

contents:  [{
  title: 'Test Content IV',
  type: 'link',
  category: 'Category, Fall Prevention, This is testing',
  keywords: 'tset,test',
  updated_at: 2024-05-13T12:21:28.018Z,
  is_disabled: true
},
{
  title: 'This is testing for linting PR',
  type: 'link',
  category: 'This Is Testing, Competency Checklists',
  keywords: 'sing',
  updated_at: 2024-04-30T14:21:52.948Z,
  is_disabled: false
}]

see content is single but multiple categories means categories should be assigned to a single property as category but all the categories associated with the content comma separated string.
